# How do you say "She was generous with her time"?

Tags: translation

How do you translate this sentence into Chinese:

> She was generous with her time.

My attempt is:

她花了很多時間陪我們。

Is there a better, more idiomatic way of saying this?

Comment: 她花了很多时间帮助我们（别人）。 她尽量协助别人。（cf。jukuu http://jukuu.com/search.php?q=generous+with+time）

Comment: Possibly "她很高興陪我們."  Literally, she was happy to accompany us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> She was generous with her time.

If you translate this phrase literally, it would be "對(花)時間她是慷慨的" (She was generous with her time). But we Chinese usually do not use the term '慷慨(generous) ' to describe the manner of spending time. We usually use  '慷慨' to describe the manner of disbursing money.

Translate the phrase like this clearly shows it's a straight translation of an English sentence. In this instance, it is better to use the verb phrase '不計較(do not care) ' instead of the adjective '慷慨'

> 她不計較花時間 (she did not care spending her time)

Depend on context, you can also interpret the phrase in different ways:

**If she's always this way:**

> "她對付出時間這一方面十分慷慨"
>
> (In regard of disbursing her time, she is very generous)

**If you are referring how she acted in one instance**:

> "她慷慨地付出她的時間"
>   (She generously disbursed her time)
>
> "她不吝惜撥出自己的時間"
>   (she was not stingy about allocating her time)

Answer (score 0):

A teacher takes a lot of time, more than she has to, helping you.（Maybe she fancies you!) Bypass the word 'generous' but catch the meaning:

她在我身上花了很多时间。

Answer (score 0):

you'd butter put this sentence in specific condition.generally say，她乐于花时间 to do sth.

Answer (score 0):

Literal translation: 她不吝惜时间。

Depending on the context, you can further embellish it a little.

> 她（很）乐于助人。
>
> 她（非常）乐于助人，不吝惜自己的时间。
>
> 她（很）热心，不吝惜时间帮助他人。
>
> 她人非常好，热心肠，帮人帮到底，送佛送上西，一点也不吝惜自己的时间。

The last one is actually a little far-fetched.

I like the the second one best, especially with the idiomatic expression `乐于助人`.